# Last In Last Out in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have 90 IDs that I need to something like on the image below. I want the last ID to be popped first and if there are new IDs added to the stack I want to push them on the end of it. Last In Last Out. Does something like this exists already? I know I could use other collection implementations but I wonder if there is a stack like this already made.

[image]

Comment: "I want the last ID to be popped first" would be Last In First Out, i.e., a normal stack.

Comment: Make it an answer Wooble, I was dumb while I was posting this question and now I can`t delete it.

Comment: @Breakpoint So what do you want to have? LIFO or FIFO? Everything (including your picture) is about FIFO except the part "I want the last ID to be popped first" which is LIFO.

Comment: It is very uncommon to talk about LILO. It's much more common logical equivalent is FIFO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is an interface with multiple implementations (including such things as blocking queues suitable for multi-threaded solutions)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have a `FIFO (first-in-first-out)` queue.

First have a look at Javadoc from [java.util.Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

There exist several implementations:

- [java.util.LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
- [java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)
- [java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Queue<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may use sort of a `Queue<E>` implementation which is provided by java (see [queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implementations).

Another possible Option would be to use a `LinkedList<E>` (see.: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

It offers all methods you need. Especially because your description seems so if you are not totally sure about the behavior you want.

A `Queue<E>` should be preferred over a `LinkedList<E>` at least for large collections without the need of random access.

Comment: Among Deque implementations LinkedList is an oddity; for example, it is alone in permitting null elements, which are discouraged by the Queue interface because of the common use of null as a special value. As an implementation of Deque, LinkedList is unlikely to be very popular. Now, the only likely reason for using LinkedList as a queue or deque implementation would be that you also needed random access to the elements. With LinkedList, even that comes at a high price; because random access has to be implemented by linear search, it has time complexity of O(n). Use ArrayDeque instead.

Comment: Thats totally true. I only added this solution as well because the op seems not to be so sure about what he wants. But i will modify my post in repsect of queues being superior.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a normal queue implementation, with the elements added to the queue in reverse order to start off with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to get you started:

```
private static BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    // Start a thread that puts stuff on the queue
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    queue.put("Some message");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Handle interruption
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // Start a thread that takes stuff from the queue (LILO)
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String message = queue.take(); // Waits if necessary for something to arrive
                    // Do something with message
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Handle interruption
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    Thread.currentThread().wait();
}
```

Comment: Why not subclassing `Thread` with your anonymous classes instead of implementing `Runnable`? You can get rid of some boilerplate code and the benefits of implementing `Runnable` do not exist for anonymous classes. Or do I miss something?

Comment: You need a thread-safe implementation of `Queue` in your use case here. Actually you're using signature of `BlockingQueue` which must be thread-safe by convention. Maybe you should mention that.

Comment: Oops - left out the queue declaration :) Thanks.